# Invalid procedure call or argument when passing parameters from VBA to WIndows DLL

Tags: c++, vba, dll, visual-studio-2017, invalid-argument

I have 64 bit windows 10 with MS Office 64 bit. I am trying to get the VBA for PowerPoint to load and execute a function in a self-written 64 bit windows DLL.

The problem I am having is that I get an exception - which I think is due to stack handling.
The dll contains (exports done in def file):

```
void _stdcall jastrNR(LPCWSTR strg1, LPCWSTR strg2, LPCWSTR strg3, LPCWSTR strg4)
```

The VBA contains:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub jastrNR Lib "<DLL path>" (ByVal arg1 As LongPtr, ByVal arg2 As LongPtr, ByVal arg3 As LongPtr, ByVal arg4 As LongPtr)

Sub Play1()
Dim s1 As String
Dim p1 As LongPtr
Dim y As Long
y = 0
MsgBox y
s1 = "123abc"
p1 = StrPtr(s1)
jastrNR p1, p1, p1, p1
p4 = StrPtr(s4)
MsgBox y  *** here I get exception or "invalid procedure call or argument" message
End Sub
```

If I print out the test string in the DLL, I do see correct data, ie 123abc
If the parameters are long, ints, there is no problem.
Also there is no problem if I make jastrNR return a long.
I have also tried to match the parameters in the C++:

```
void _stdcall jastrNR(LONG_PTR strg1, LONG_PTR strg2, LONG_PTR strg3, LONG_PTR strg4)
```

I get the same exceptions.

In Visual Studio 2017, I have set (under C++ settings) the calling convention to be __stdcall (/Gz).
I have noticed in the linker map output:

```
?jastrNR@@YAX_J000@Z (void __cdecl jastrNR(__int64,__int64,__int64,__int64))
           exported name: jastrNR
```

The __cdecl concerns me as I thought I should have seen __stdcall

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: `_stdcall` and `_cdecl` only apply to 32-bit, they are ignored by 64-bit compilers. There is [only 1 calling convention in 64-bit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx), and it is dictated by the 64-bit ABI. So this is unlikely to be a calling convention issue. My guess is the DLL is doing something wrong and is corrupting memory. Please show the actual source code for `jastrNR()`.

Comment: @Remy : thanks for that. After much more experimenting I realised I must have had an illegal character in the vba script which only caused a problem at runtime. After re-writing the code, all is fine.